# LSTM Network Converge at high loss and won't decrease anymore

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

So I am trying to build a LSTM neural network (however many layers) for the music generation from some of my favourite game background musics.
Things were going well until this happened:

```
/350
12/12 [==============================] - 6s 507ms/step - loss: 10.5694
Epoch 2/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 9.6112
Epoch 3/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.9602
Epoch 4/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 207ms/step - loss: 7.3792
Epoch 5/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 207ms/step - loss: 7.2705
Epoch 6/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.2140
Epoch 7/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 207ms/step - loss: 7.1895
Epoch 8/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 210ms/step - loss: 7.1732
Epoch 9/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 209ms/step - loss: 7.1647
Epoch 10/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 209ms/step - loss: 7.1603
Epoch 11/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 212ms/step - loss: 7.1578
Epoch 12/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1505
Epoch 13/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 207ms/step - loss: 7.1498
Epoch 14/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1519
Epoch 15/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1309
Epoch 16/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1429
Epoch 17/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1398
Epoch 18/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1424
Epoch 19/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1377
Epoch 20/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 208ms/step - loss: 7.1470
Epoch 21/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1526
Epoch 22/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1357
Epoch 23/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 207ms/step - loss: 7.1414
Epoch 24/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 211ms/step - loss: 7.1242
Epoch 25/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1393
Epoch 26/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1407
Epoch 27/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 201ms/step - loss: 7.1334
Epoch 28/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 201ms/step - loss: 7.1241
Epoch 29/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 201ms/step - loss: 7.1442
Epoch 30/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 202ms/step - loss: 7.1394
Epoch 31/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 213ms/step - loss: 7.1367
Epoch 32/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 212ms/step - loss: 7.1311
Epoch 33/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1363
Epoch 34/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1359
Epoch 35/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 209ms/step - loss: 7.1327
Epoch 36/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1388
Epoch 37/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1386
Epoch 38/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 200ms/step - loss: 7.1253
Epoch 39/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 212ms/step - loss: 7.1340
Epoch 40/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 207ms/step - loss: 7.1371
Epoch 41/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1395
Epoch 42/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1420
Epoch 43/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1275
Epoch 44/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 218ms/step - loss: 7.1320
Epoch 45/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 217ms/step - loss: 7.1219
Epoch 46/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 217ms/step - loss: 7.1326
Epoch 47/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 219ms/step - loss: 7.1376
Epoch 48/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 212ms/step - loss: 7.1337
Epoch 49/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1357
Epoch 50/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1381
Epoch 51/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1307
Epoch 52/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1365
Epoch 53/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 202ms/step - loss: 7.1241
Epoch 54/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 202ms/step - loss: 7.1415
Epoch 55/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1417
Epoch 56/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1366
Epoch 57/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 210ms/step - loss: 7.1265
Epoch 58/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1153
Epoch 59/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1216
Epoch 60/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1312
Epoch 61/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1287
Epoch 62/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1293
Epoch 63/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 201ms/step - loss: 7.1258
Epoch 64/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1427
Epoch 65/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1436
Epoch 66/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1246
Epoch 67/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1362
Epoch 68/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1276
Epoch 69/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1458
Epoch 70/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1211
Epoch 71/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 208ms/step - loss: 7.1392
Epoch 72/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 206ms/step - loss: 7.1237
Epoch 73/350
12/12 [==============================] - 3s 212ms/step - loss: 7.1331
Epoch 74/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 208ms/step - loss: 7.1296
Epoch 75/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 207ms/step - loss: 7.1350
Epoch 76/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1374
Epoch 77/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 200ms/step - loss: 7.1260
Epoch 78/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 202ms/step - loss: 7.1256
Epoch 79/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1322
Epoch 80/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 202ms/step - loss: 7.1272
Epoch 81/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1294
Epoch 82/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1278
Epoch 83/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1401
Epoch 84/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 204ms/step - loss: 7.1340
Epoch 85/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 205ms/step - loss: 7.1475
Epoch 86/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 208ms/step - loss: 7.1237
Epoch 87/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 203ms/step - loss: 7.1229
Epoch 88/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 202ms/step - loss: 7.1228
Epoch 89/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 201ms/step - loss: 7.1223
Epoch 90/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 199ms/step - loss: 7.1333
Epoch 91/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 199ms/step - loss: 7.1259
Epoch 92/350
12/12 [==============================] - 2s 201ms/step - loss: 7.1345
Epoch 93/350
 6/12 [==============>...............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.1446
```

As you can see, the training loss rapidly decrease at first few epochs (about 1~3) and then it suddenly converges very early at a high loss. This is especially so confusing because I had trained a similar network several times before (with a even larger dataset) and this sort of issue never happened. Please note that above history is from a reduced amount of dataset (approx 1/10 of the dataset), however even with the full dataset the problem remains exactly the same.

Things I have tried:

- Increasing/Decreasing batch size, learning rate
- Adding/Removing L2 regularization / Dropout layers
- Increasing/Decreasing the amount of dataset
- Adding/Removing more LSTM layers
- Searched through all similar cases in stackoverflow and tried everything they said but it won't work

I don't see any problem with the dataset, because I have previously successfully trained a simmilar dataset with the network. If you wonder, the dataset was generated by parsing 150 MIDI songs with MIDO python library into a stringified list of MID messages.
Of course, I have encoded them into integer by creating dictionaries as well.

Here's the code for more detail:

```
import tensorflow_core as v2
import pickle
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers


with open('drive/My Drive/maple_AI/data_list.txt','rb') as file:
    data_list = pickle.load(file)

print('data size:',len(data_list))

print(data_list[0:1000])

# sequence_length = 200
sequence_length = 100

#5500:2 and 5500:128 works

dataset = v2.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_list[:])

dataset = dataset.batch(sequence_length,drop_remainder=True)

def map_function(chunk):
    input_data = chunk[:-1]
    output_data = chunk[1:]
    return input_data,output_data

dataset = dataset.map(map_function)

batch_size = 128

dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000).batch(batch_size,drop_remainder=True)

vocab_size = 39859

def build_model():
    input_init = v2.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,),batch_size=batch_size)
    embedded_input = v2.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size,output_dim=150)(input_init)
    lstm_one = v2.keras.layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True,stateful=True)(embedded_input)
    dropout_one = v2.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(lstm_one)
    lstm_two = v2.keras.layers.LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,stateful=True)(dropout_one)
    dropout_one_2 = v2.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(lstm_two)
    # lstm_three = v2.keras.layers.LSTM(256,return_sequences=True,stateful=True,recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')(dropout_one_2)
    # dense_one = v2.keras.layers.Dense(256)(lstm_three)
    # dropout_two = v2.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(dense_one)

    # lstm_four = v2.keras.layers.LSTM(128,return_sequences=True,stateful=True,recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')(dropout_two)
    # dense_two = v2.keras.layers.Dense(128)(lstm_four)
    # dropout_three = v2.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)(dense_two)

    dense_three = v2.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)(dropout_one_2)
    return v2.keras.Model(inputs=input_init,outputs=dense_three)

model = build_model()

def loss(labels,logits):
    return v2.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels,logits,True)

#0.00001
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),loss=loss)

print(model.summary())

checkpoint_callback = v2.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='drive/My Drive/maple_AI/maple_music_parameters', save_weights_only=True)

# weights_list = model.trainable_weights
# gradients = v2.gradients(model.output,weights_list)
# f = v2.function([model.input],gradients)

# llback = v2.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch,logs : print("\nweights\n",model.optimizer.get_gradients(model.total_loss,model.trainable_weights).values[0]))
model.fit(dataset,epochs=350,callbacks=[])
```

I hope this presents enough information. I would really appreciate prompt replies.

Comment: are you sure about the loss function you are using,have you checked it for other loss.

Comment: Yep. I am quite sure, but it's never 100%. Do you have any other loss function that I think I must have used?

Comment: Use sparse categorical crossentropy when your classes are mutually exclusive (e.g. when each sample belongs exactly to one class) and categorical crossentropy when one sample can have multiple classes or labels are soft probabilities (like [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]). (You may want to check this)

You can also try a different optimizer, say `Nadam` or `RMSProp`.

Comment: The first step is always to try and get the network to perform well on the training data, then once you're sure it can do that, aim for validation. This means removing all regularisation and allowing over fitting. This will give you an indication of if it's the complexity of the data that's causing your issue, or an error in the model.

Comment: Well, I have tried Nadam and RMSprop and I did manage to bring the loss down to around 5. However, at this point the rate of train is so slow that its going to take months to complete.. the strange thing is that I have tried setting the learning rate to even 1000 and it hardly affects the training speed. What could this mean?